# Access column by position or index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a list as follows and I search it in a csv file to get the item code associate with it. E.g.,  for 0 -> item code is 11nm

```
L = [0, 2]

CSV file:
0, 11nm
1, 22nm
2, 33nm
3, 44nm
```

I am currently doing it as follows.

```
df = pd.read_csv('item_code.csv', sep = ',')
item_codes= df[df["No"].isin(L)]["item_code"].tolist()
```

However, now I want to know how to do the same thing for a csv file when the file headings (No, item_code) is unavailable.

Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the column names are unavailable, you can refer to them by index using `df.iloc`:

```
item_codes = df[df.iloc[:, 0].isin(L)].iloc[:, 1].tolist()
```

---

MCVE:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

text = \
'''0, 11nm
1, 22nm
2, 33nm
3, 44nm'''

buf = io.StringIO(text)    
df = pd.read_csv(buf, sep=',\s*', header=None, engine='python') # no column names
print(df) 

   0     1
0  0  11nm
1  1  22nm
2  2  33nm
3  3  44nm

L = [0, 2]
item_codes = df[df.iloc[:, 0].isin(L)].iloc[:, 1]
print(item_codes)

0    11nm
2    33nm
Name: 1, dtype: object

print(item_codes.tolist())
['11nm', '33nm']
```

Notes:

- `sep=',\s*'` is a regex pattern (to specify column delimiters)
- `header=None` will prevent any rows from being assigned
- `engine='python'` to select the regex engine

Answer (score 2):

You can use parameter `names` for specify columns names, for select column use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('item_code.csv', names=['No','item_code'])
print (df)
   No item_code
0   0      11nm
1   1      22nm
2   2      33nm
3   3      44nm


item_codes= df.loc[df["No"].isin(L), "item_code"].tolist()
print (item_codes)
['11nm', '33nm']
```

Or use parameter `header=None` for default columns names `0,1...`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('item_code.csv', header=None)

print (df)
   0     1
0  0  11nm
1  1  22nm
2  2  33nm
3  3  44nm

#first column selected by position with iloc
item_codes= df.loc[df.iloc[:,0].isin(L), 1].tolist()
print (item_codes)
['11nm', '33nm']
```

---

```
#first column selected by column name
item_codes= df.loc[df[0].isin(L), 1].tolist()
print (item_codes)
['11nm', '33nm']
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading the csv file with `header=None`, to let pandas know that you don't have a header in your file:

```
df = pd.read_csv('item_code.csv', sep = ',', header=None)
```

You can use the column index instead of the column name.

Like this :

```
df[df[0].isin(L)][1].tolist()
```

or this :

```
df[df.iloc[:,0].isin(L)][1].tolist()
```

---

#### Explanation:

if you print the dataframe after reading it without header with `print(df)`

```
   0     1
0  0  11nm
1  1  22nm
2  2  33nm
3  3  44nm
```

You will notice that pandas assigns the number `[0,1]` to the column names instead of the `["No", "item_code"]` that weren't present as a header. Thus, you can reference each column with its index like this `df[0]` or `df.iloc[:, 0]`.

The latter `df.iloc[:, 0]` tells pandas to take all rows and only column `0`.